# How to create a local webserver in cordova android app to use a-frame

Tags: android, file, cordova, https, localserver

I'm trying to use a-frame in my Cordova android app but when I try to access other local files or https websites I get an error telling me I can't work from file://:

`HTML file is currently being served via the file:// protocol. Assets, textures, and models WILL NOT WORK due to cross-origin policy! Please use a local or hosted server`

My question is: how can I use a local server in my Cordova app? or are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a hostname to your app

```
 <preference name="hostname" value="com.myapp" />
```

So your content is served over `https://com.myapp` then you will load from `https` and not `file://` anymore

Comment: Could you add more detail, like where to put the line of code, and how it works?

Comment: in your config.xml

Comment: I have tried this but going to https: //com.myapp doesn't work. It tells me that the web page is not available